# How to find which users logged in in the last 30 minutes UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-16.04

I need to create a command to find all the users that logged in the system in the past 30 minutes. The command can be split in multiple commands as I intend to call it from python. For example:

```
1. Command to find all users in system
2. Loop all users in python
3. Ask if the iterated user logged in the system in the past 30 min.
4. If so, add iterated user to recentUsersList.
```

From this, I only need step 3.

Comment: Look at `last`: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/last.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last -s -30m` should be what you're looking for. `last` shows a history of logged in users and `-s 30m` constrains it to the last 30 minutes. You could also cleanse input to only showing users with the command `last -s -30m --fullnames|head -n -1|awk '{print $1}|sort -u'`. Be careful because last will also print out the "user" `reboot` which only shows when the system rebooted and is not an actual user.

Comment: Do you know why the full name of the users isn't displayed? My user is called python_user but it just says python_u

Comment: Does `whoami` output python_user or python_u?

Comment: whoami returns python_user

Comment: This worked for me. Update the answer so I can check it:  last -s -30m --fullnames

Comment: Even better... last -s -30m --fullnames |head -n -1|awk '{print $1}' | sort -u

Comment: Nice job figuring that out! I didn't notice because I use short usernames.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get the information with "loginctl show-user ".

Comment: You may want to consider posting 'qualified' (may, might, etc..) comments as *comments* rather than answers. Especially in this case where if you posted your 'answer' as a comment, you would still have over 350 characters left unused in the comment. No ding this time, but do try and be judicious in providing comments as comments and answers as answers.

Comment: Good job improving the community without the hate. Thanks.